# PowerPoint: Autosaved versions disappear after saving file

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I was working on a presentation in PowerPoint when I accidentally deleted some content in it. Undo did not help, but I saw there are several older auto-saved versions listed in the *File* menu.

I thought it was a good idea to first save the current document (I added some new content before I noticed that I deleted the wrong parts), which I did. But after that the auto-saved version were not listed any more. This looks very counter-intuitive (unless I were only after old versions and had no new content).

Are those now permanently deleted? If yes, can the behavior be changed?

Screenshot as per request:
[image]

Comment: This is a question for SuperUser here on StackExchange rather than StackOverflow, which for questions relating to programming problems you're trying to solve.  I'd repost your question there, and if you do, please explain where exactly you're seeing these auto-saved versions (a screenshot would be even better).  I mention that because PowerPoint doesn't normally show you autosaved versions unless you've just started it after a previous crash.

Answer (score 0):

AutoSave/AutoRecover was designed to recover information in the event of a power failure, windows/system crash, or other error in Office. Multiple sources advise its ['not a substitute for regularly saving your work'](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Automatically-save-and-recover-Office-files-5baa2030-9768-4c6c-8d2a-1e10a8d741b1). Regarding your questions:

I couldn't find a direct answer whether normal 'Saves' were designed to overwrite 'AutoSave/AutoRecover' files. I'm guessing it was though & I don't think there is anyway to change that behavior. I'll agree the 'Manage Versions' wording can be a little misconstruing, but after clicking it does show 'Recover Unsaved'. Treat this as a learning exercise & if you made a change you didn't mean to then do a File, Save As. Some more links relating:

- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Help-protect-your-files-in-case-of-a-crash-551c29b1-6a4b-4415-a3ff-a80415b92f99
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/107686
- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/recover-an-Office-file-4bddecb7-bf4f-4aad-b1b3-dab1633b5bbf
- http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Recover-lost-or-deleted-files